# Spring Security - Process custom annotation in GenericFilterBean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

in my controller I have a custom annotation like:

```
@GetMapping("/apikey")
@Secured(apiKeys = { ApiKey.APP_1})  // <- Custom annotation
public ResponseEntity startApiKey() {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("ApiKey approved");
}
```

In my Spring Security Config I have added a Filter for checking the apikey and authentication:

```
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader(ApiKeyHeadername.DEFAULTHEADERNAME.getHeadername());
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "N/A";
}

@Override
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
        String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (!ApiKey.APP_1.getApiKey().equals(principal))
        {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
        }
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        return authentication;
    });
 }
}
```

Before the custom annotation was proccessed within a AspectJ class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SecurityAspect {

@Autowired
private IPrincipal principal;

@Autowired
private AuthorizationManager authorizationManager;

@Pointcut("@annotation(my.demo.application.security.aspect.Secured)")
public void methodAnnotatedWithSecured() {
}

@Around("methodAnnotatedWithSecured()")
public Object userAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Secured securedAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Secured.class);

    Authorized securityInformation = new Authorized(securedAnnotation.apiKeys(), securedAnnotation.roles(),
            securedAnnotation.usernames());

    if (authorizationManager.authorizeUserPrincipal(principal,
            securityInformation) == AuthorizationState.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        throw DefaultNotAuthorizedExceptionFactory.createNotAuthorizedException();
    }

    return joinPoint.proceed();
}

}
```

How can I process the annotation informations in the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, or how can i get the annotation by Reflection in this Filter. Or can I inject something to get it?

Thank you in advice

Comment: Why go custom and not use Spring's `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` instead. You can have fine-grained config with have roles and privileges. A good tutorial can be found here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: Because the custom annotations still exists.